# How to show only two button in single row

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using *ngFor for displaying multiple buttons, it can have many buttons. Currently I am getting all the buttons in one column, means one below one.

But I want to display only 2 buttons in a row, means, in above case these green buttons should be in one line, and 2 red buttons should be in next line just below of it. How can I do this?

This is I tried:

```
<div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div *ngFor="let actionButton of actionButtonData">
              <div *ngIf="actionButton.Direction === 1">
                <button type="button" class="btn actionButton btn-success">
                  {{ actionButton.Name }}
                </button>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="actionButton.Direction === 2">
                <button type="button" class="btn actionButton btn-danger">
                  {{ actionButton.Name }}
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

> css

```
.actionButton {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

Comment: ca you add your css code also @techguy

Comment: @Aahad added ...please check

Comment: you have added a lot of empty div remove them and check!

Comment: did you checked?

Comment: @Aahad I tried differe way. And its working

Answer (score 2):

> 

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='row'>
        <button >
          button1
        </button>
        <button >
          button2
        </button>
    </div>
        <div class='row'>
        <button >
          button1
        </button>
        <button >
          button2
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

try this row col method

Answer (score 0):

you could group buttons in bootstrap. for your purpose, add btn-group class to ngIf div. it's bootstrap feature and you don't need any custom css.

```html
    <div class="row mt-3">
          <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div *ngFor="let actionButton of actionButtonData">
              <div *ngIf="actionButton.Direction === 1" class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn actionButton btn-success">
                  {{ actionButton.Name }}
                </button>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="actionButton.Direction === 2" class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn actionButton btn-danger">
                  {{ actionButton.Name }}
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it by using normal bootstrap, add class `row` to parent div and add class `col-sm-6` to every child will make only 2 children in that row

```html
<div *ngFor="let actionButton of actionButtonData" class="row">             <!--here-->
              <div *ngIf="actionButton.Direction === 1" class="col-sm-6">   <!--here-->
                <button type="button" class="btn actionButton btn-success">
                  {{ actionButton.Name }}
                </button>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="actionButton.Direction === 2" class="col-sm-6">    <!--here-->
                <button type="button" class="btn actionButton btn-danger">
                  {{ actionButton.Name }}
                </button>
              </div>
</div>
```